# Load All in hazelcast calling multiple times

Tags: java, dictionary, hazelcast

In Hazelcast 3.3, Load keys are called once and I return 2 keys in it.
But when I comes to loadAll, it calls twice with one key as input, It performs like load() not loadAll().

For your information, I don't configure partition, neither above 1000 keys, Just have two keys.

Where Am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is correct. If you have 271 partitions, then each partition will load its own keys. In your case, you have 2 keys and they are apparently in different partitions. So therefor each partition will do a loadAll; even though it loads only single key.

Comment: Sry! Am new to hazelcast concept, I havent configured partition anywhere, What that magic number 271 denotes?? Is it a default configuration of hazelcast??? If so How to make them to call under a single call??? Whats the use of partition here?

Comment: I know you are an expertised in hazelcast, Pls answer my another question too?? Is it possible to configure TIMESTAMP and query based on time stamp in hazel cast???